# Checking JSON for Key present or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am iterating over a JSON to check if  a Key is present or not. I have intentionally manually removed all the things where key is not present.

My sample JSON is:

```
    {
    "MODELER": {
        "@version": "3",
        "MODEL": {
            "@BEGINDATE": "1970-01-01 00:00:00.0",
            "@DESCRIPTION": "SendPro C 200/300/400 (CSD 2.0) t2019.02.08 u2019.02.12",
            "@ENDDATE": "2117-05-03 08:24:36.0",
            "@ID": "I_604356",
            "@NAME": "SendProCSeries",
            "@PATH": "PB.SMB.SendProCSeries",
            "@SKU": "",
            "@SUBASSEMBLY_TYPE": "MODEL",
            "RULE": [
                {
                    "@COMMENT": "",
                    "@DEFAULTPRIORITY": "50",
                    "@DESCRIPTION": "Pick Meter Equipment",
                    "@DISABLEFLG": "N",
                    "@DefinedOutsideTree": "true",
                    "@FIRINGPHASE": "",
                    "@NAME": "PickMeterEquipment",
                    "BOOLOP": {
                        "@BOOLOP": "and",
                        "@SEQ": "0",
                        "@TYPE": "0",
                        "BOOLOP": [
                            {
                                "@BOOLOP": "or",
                                "@SEQ": "1",
                                "@TYPE": "0",
                                "FRAGMENT": [
                                    {
                                        "@FUNC1": "value",
                                        "@FUNC2": "literal",
                                        "@NULLACTION": "Fragment is false",
                                        "@OP": "=",
                                        "@PROP1": "SALES_TYPE",
                                        "@PROP2": "PURCHASE",
                                        "@SEQ": "1",
                                        "@TYPE": "1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@FUNC1": "value",
                                        "@FUNC2": "literal",
                                        "@NULLACTION": "Fragment is false",
                                        "@OP": "=",
                                        "@PROP1": "SALES_TYPE",
                                        "@PROP2": "LEASE",
                                        "@SEQ": "2",
                                        "@TYPE": "1"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "@BOOLOP": "or",
                                "@SEQ": "2",
                                "@TYPE": "0",
                                "FRAGMENT": {
                                    "@FUNC1": "value",
                                    "@FUNC2": "list",
                                    "@NULLACTION": "Fragment is false",
                                    "@OP": "in",
                                    "@PROP1": "PRICELIST",
                                    "@PROP2": "LeaseAccounting",
                                    "@SEQ": "1",
                                    "@TYPE": "1"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "@BOOLOP": "or",
                                "@SEQ": "4",
                                "@TYPE": "0",
                                "FRAGMENT": [
                                    {
                                        "@FUNC1": "value",
                                        "@FUNC2": "propval",
                                        "@NULLACTION": "Fragment is false",
                                        "@OP": "=",
                                        "@PROP1": "PICK_SKU1",
                                        "@PROP2": "._sku",
                                        "@SEQ": "1",
                                        "@TYPE": "1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "@FUNC1": "value",
                                        "@FUNC2": "propval",
                                        "@NULLACTION": "Fragment is false",
                                        "@OP": "=",
                                        "@PROP1": "PICK_SKU10",
                                        "@PROP2": "._sku",
                                        "@SEQ": "2",
                                        "@TYPE": "1"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "ACTION": [
                        {
                            "@FORMULA": "1",
                            "@PROPNAME": "",
                            "@PROPVALUE": "",
                            "@SEQ": "0",
                            "@TYPE": "1",
                            "LOCALES": null,
                            "ACTIONITEM": {
                                "@SEQ": "0",
                                "@item": ".",
                                "@max": "1",
                                "@min": "0",
                                "@qty": "1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@FORMULA": "",
                            "@PROPNAME": "_isViewable",
                            "@PROPVALUE": "1",
                            "@SEQ": "0",
                            "@TYPE": "2",
                            "LOCALES": null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "@COMMENT": "",
                    "@DEFAULTPRIORITY": "50",
                    "@DESCRIPTION": "Pick If External Selected",
                    "@DISABLEFLG": "N",
                    "@DefinedOutsideTree": "true",
                    "@FIRINGPHASE": "",
                    "@NAME": "PickIfExternalScaleSelected",
                    "@TRIGGER": "1",
                    "BOOLOP": {
                        "@BOOLOP": "and",
                        "@SEQ": "0",
                        "@TYPE": "0",
                        "FRAGMENT": [
                            {
                                "@FUNC1": "length",
                                "@FUNC2": "literal",
                                "@NULLACTION": "Fragment is false",
                                "@OP": ">",
                                "@PROP1": "ExternalScaleVal",
                                "@PROP2": "0",
                                "@SEQ": "1",
                                "@TYPE": "1"
                            },
                            {
                                "@FUNC1": "value",
                                "@FUNC2": "literal",
                                "@NULLACTION": "Fragment is false",
                                "@OP": "=",
                                "@PROP1": "_amEntitled",
                                "@PROP2": "1",
                                "@SEQ": "2",
                                "@TYPE": "1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "ACTION": {
                        "@FORMULA": "1",
                        "@PROPNAME": "",
                        "@PROPVALUE": "",
                        "@SEQ": "0",
                        "@TYPE": "1",
                        "LOCALES": null,
                        "ACTIONITEM": {
                            "@SEQ": "0",
                            "@item": ".",
                            "@max": "1",
                            "@min": "0",
                            "@qty": "1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "@COMMENT": "",
                    "@DEFAULTPRIORITY": "50",
                    "@NAME": "PickCAAA",
                    "BOOLOP": {
                        "@BOOLOP": "and",
                        "@SEQ": "0",
                        "@TYPE": "0",
                        "FRAGMENT": {
                            "@FUNC1": "value",
                            "@FUNC2": "literal",
                            "@NULLACTION": "Fragment is false",
                            "@OP": "=",
                            "@PROP1": "_description",
                            "@PROP2": "Dashboard",
                            "@SEQ": "1",
                            "@TYPE": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    "ACTION": {
                        "@FORMULA": "1",
                        "@PROPNAME": "",
                        "@PROPVALUE": "",
                        "@SEQ": "0",
                        "@TYPE": "1",
                        "LOCALES": null,
                        "ACTIONITEM": {
                            "@SEQ": "0",
                            "@item": ".",
                            "@max": "1",
                            "@min": "0",
                            "@qty": "1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "@COMMENT": "",
                    "@DEFAULTPRIORITY": "50",
                    "@DESCRIPTION": "Pick ERB4 when ZHD8",
                    "@DISABLEFLG": "N",
                    "@FIRINGPHASE": "",
                    "@NAME": "AUTOSELECT: ERB4",
                    "@RULECLASSIFICATION": "PICK",
                    "@TRIGGER": "1",
                    "BOOLOP": {
                        "@BOOLOP": "and",
                        "@SEQ": "0",
                        "@TYPE": "0",
                        "FRAGMENT": {
                            "@FUNC1": "value",
                            "@FUNC2": "literal",
                            "@NULLACTION": "Fragment is false",
                            "@OP": "=",
                            "@PROP1": "_sku",
                            "@PROP2": "ZHD8",
                            "@SEQ": "1",
                            "@TYPE": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    "ACTION": [
                        {
                            "@FORMULA": "1",
                            "@PROPNAME": "",
                            "@PROPVALUE": "",
                            "@SEQ": "0",
                            "@TYPE": "1",
                            "LOCALES": null,
                            "ACTIONITEM": {
                                "@SEQ": "0",
                                "@item": ".",
                                "@max": "1",
                                "@min": "0",
                                "@qty": "1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@FORMULA": "",
                            "@PROPNAME": "_isViewable",
                            "@PROPVALUE": "1",
                            "@SEQ": "0",
                            "@TYPE": "2",
                            "LOCALES": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to check whether a particular child key is present n my JSON or not. For that I have written a function which should print a parent key based on a child key condition.

The function looks like this:

```
def getTargetPickRules(json_rule_data):
    for i in json_rule_data['MODELER']['MODEL']['RULE']:
        if 'ACTION' not in i:
            continue

        if 'ACTIONITEM' not in i['ACTION']:
            continue

        print("Rule Name - %s %s" % (i['@NAME'],i['ACTION']))
```

Ideally the Expected output should be:

```
Rule Name - PickMeterEquipment [{'@FORMULA': '1', '@PROPNAME': '', '@PROPVALUE': '', '@SEQ': '0', '@TYPE': '1', 'LOCALES': None, 'ACTIONITEM': {'@SEQ': '0', '@item': '.', '@max': '1', '@min': '0', '@qty': '1'}}, {'@FORMULA': '', '@PROPNAME': '_isViewable', '@PROPVALUE': '1', '@SEQ': '0', '@TYPE': '2', 'LOCALES': None}]
Rule Name - PickIfExternalScaleSelected {'@FORMULA': '1', '@PROPNAME': '', '@PROPVALUE': '', '@SEQ': '0', '@TYPE': '1', 'LOCALES': None, 'ACTIONITEM': {'@SEQ': '0', '@item': '.', '@max': '1', '@min': '0', '@qty': '1'}}
Rule Name - PickCAAA {'@FORMULA': '1', '@PROPNAME': '', '@PROPVALUE': '', '@SEQ': '0', '@TYPE': '1', 'LOCALES': None, 'ACTIONITEM': {'@SEQ': '0', '@item': '.', '@max': '1', '@min': '0', '@qty': '1'}}
Rule Name - AUTOSELECT: ERB4 [{'@FORMULA': '1', '@PROPNAME': '', '@PROPVALUE': '', '@SEQ': '0', '@TYPE': '1', 'LOCALES': None, 'ACTIONITEM': {'@SEQ': '0', '@item': '.', '@max': '1', '@min': '0', '@qty': '1'}}, {'@FORMULA': '', '@PROPNAME': '_isViewable', '@PROPVALUE': '1', '@SEQ': '0', '@TYPE': '2', 'LOCALES': None}]
```

If you see my JSON all the `ACTION` keys has `ACTIONITEM` but it is only outputting 2 of them. Here is what my Actual output is:

```
Rule Name - PickIfExternalScaleSelected {'@FORMULA': '1', '@PROPNAME': '', '@PROPVALUE': '', '@SEQ': '0', '@TYPE': '1', 'LOCALES': None, 'ACTIONITEM': {'@SEQ': '0', '@item': '.', '@max': '1', '@min': '0', '@qty': '1'}}
Rule Name - PickCAAA {'@FORMULA': '1', '@PROPNAME': '', '@PROPVALUE': '', '@SEQ': '0', '@TYPE': '1', 'LOCALES': None, 'ACTIONITEM': {'@SEQ': '0', '@item': '.', '@max': '1', '@min': '0', '@qty': '1'}}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with pdb?

Comment: Yes , I have tried to debug. The items which are not printing have two ACTION keys. But this doesn't ignore the fact that ACTIONITEM is present in one of them

Comment: Have you tried running my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is inconsistent:
Some Action dictionaries contain a dictionary (where this dictionery has the element `"ACTIONITEM"`), but some contain a list (starting with a `[`). Either the data is wrong or you have to specifiy your desired behavior more precisely.

Comment: Yes , you are correct and I have put another filter to check if the input is list or dict

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue is that you have multiple ACTIONs in some entries. When you load a json into a dictionary using the json module, the default behaviour of the library in case of duplicate keys is to keep the latest value of the duplicate key. This is because dictionaries in python cannot have duplicate keys. In your case, the version of ACTION that was later in the json did not have an ACTIONITEM.

Example:

```
>>> import json
>>> dic = json.loads('{"a": "b", "a": "c"}')
>>> dic
{u'a': u'c'}
>>> dic = json.loads('{"a": "c", "a": "b"}')
{u'a': u'b'}
```